# PHP UTF-8 to ISO-8859-1 issue on encoding

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8

I have text coming from a SOAP service that i need to input into my mysql DB

text comes from SOAP in UTF-8 and MySQL tables are set to latin1_swedish_ci

I found how to fix the problem on my old server, we just moved to a new server and script are not working any more

My test string is this "abc €ùÁÄÅ def ‘O’"

If i don't change the string i just update the database the fist part "€ùÁÄÅ" don't have issue but the second mess up into "âOâ"

if i use

```
$mySql = iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1//IGNORE", $mySql);
```

i lose "€ùÁÄÅ" and "‘O’" part of the string

if i use

```
$mySql = iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1//TRANSLIT", $mySql);
```

this is what i was using on old server, but on new server I lose the all string
$mySql is empty

if i use

```
$mySql = utf8_decode($mySql);
```

i get question marks "abc ????? def ?O?"

Comment: Silly question but why do you have to use latin1_swedish_ci for your database, why not use utf8 for the db as well? (utf8mb4 if you can)

Comment: because is old website and needs to migrate to utf-8 but, i was hoping later on

Comment: Do not use any conversion functions; go UTF-8 all the way.